# HDMI not functioning

Tags: hdmi

I recently  bought a HDMI to DVI cable for my monitor which takes VGA input. It works fine with windows on laptop. In raspberry pi, it "blinks". The screen goes off and again the pre-built logo animation of the monitor. In ubuntu, the screen is sometimes supported, sometimes, it also "blinks".

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that your monitor only has VGA input, and you're trying to go HDMI->DVI->VGA?

Comment: Agreed. @dam-underscore: Because the Pi's HDMI uses digital, it would have to be converted to analog before being transferred to VGA, which is analog all of which Gerben has mentioned. I heard of a DVI cable that was custom made and handled USB, VGA, *and* sound. Obviously, DVI can be rather quirky. The fact that Ubuntu also blinks (and Windows doesn't) *might* point to an issue with X11 server(s) and your HDMI/VGA converter, as both Raspbian and Ubuntu use (as of now) X11 for GUIs, though I can't be certain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are out of luck. A DVI cable has lines for both digital, and analog signal. The Pi will only send data over the digital lines, while you monitor (being a VGA monitor) only listens to the analog lines.

DVI cables are kind of weird in that way. The can even carry USB signals.

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late for OP, but try config_hdmi_boost=4 or even config_hdmi_boost=7. This tends to improve blinking issues.

You can change this by editing config.txt: `sudo nano /boot/config.txt` - for more info see [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md).

Comment: Can you provide some more detail on *where* these settings should be changed?

Comment: @gobering - sure, I've added instructions to my answer.